# MySQL Server Connection in PhpStorm 2016

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

This seems like the most annoying thing in the world, but for some odd reason, I'm not able to connect my MySQL DB in PhpStorm (as a data source). It constantly tells me that the user/password combo is incorrect. Here's the complete error message:

> The specified user/password combination is rejected: [28000][1045] Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

I know for a fact that my credentials are correct. I've checked and double checked. Even created a few new users.

I know that the credentials are correct because the application I'm writing is successfully connected to this DB.

And, as an FYI, the DB I'm trying to connect to is hosted on GoDaddy (shared CPanel Linux hosting).

PS: I've also tried using my website's IP as the host to no avail.

Comment: So ... the host is GoDaddy hosting and not local computer, right? How do you connect -- do you use direct connection or maybe over SSH? Do you have exact instructions from GoDaddy on how to connect to MySQL from your computer? **So far the IDE is right** (based on your description and knowing how GoDaddy works). Your app is working because it's running on GoDaddy servers already .. and GoDaddy does not allow connections to MySQL from outside of their network (typical hosting provider would do the same). if you have different fact -- please share 0with screenshots or links)

Comment: I found that connections to MySQL via PHPStorm are much easier using SFTP or SSH tunnelling, you need to log in to yor CPanel account (via the SFTP tab in PhpStorm) and the use `localhost`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Martin - Tried SSH to no avail. I keep getting the "Connection to MySQL - myDB@localhost failed: SSH: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset." error

Comment: Ok, try using the SFTP tunnelling.